# A maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Suppose that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Consider the elliptic boundary value problem for $\phi=\phi(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{equation}%%\label{eqn: cn cp phi system with steric effect stationary solns}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta \phi\geq \eta(\phi^{\ast})(\phi-\phi_0)\quad \text{in}\quad\hspace{2.5mm} \Omega,\\
\hspace{7mm}\phi=0 \hspace{28mm} \text{on}\quad \partial\Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\eta(\phi^{\ast})<0$, for some $\phi^{\ast}\in\mathbb{R}^1$  and $\phi_0\in\mathbb{R}^1$ is arbitrary. Does this problem enjoy the maximum principle? In other words, could we conclude that $\phi>0$ in $\Omega$?

Comment: Indeed, let $w=\phi-\phi_0$, then $w$ satisfies
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta w\geq \eta(\phi^{\ast})\,w\quad \text{in}\quad\hspace{2.5mm} \Omega,\\
\hspace{7mm}w=-\phi_0 \hspace{7mm} \text{on}\quad \partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
$$The maximum principle leads to $w>-\phi_0$ in $\Omega$, i.e. $\phi>0$ in $\Omega$. Is this argument correct?

Comment: Argument is correct only if $\phi_0$ is negative. Such an assumption is not in the question statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. According To Corollary 3.2 in Gilbarg-Trudinger, $\phi_0$ should be positive so that $inf_{\partial\Omega} w^{-}=-\phi_0$

Comment: Someone provided me a counter example. As $\phi_0<0$, the conclusion cannot be true, as shown by the following example: Let $\Omega=(-1,1)$ and $\phi=x^2-1$. Then it is easy to see that $\phi=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and $\Delta \phi=-2\geq (-1)(\phi-(-100000))$ in $\Omega$, where $\eta(\phi^{\ast})=-1$ and $\phi_0=-100000$. However, $\phi=x^2-1<0$ in $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the sign of $\phi_0$. You have
$$
-\Delta \phi -\eta(\phi^*)\phi \ge -\eta(\phi^*)\phi_0.
$$
If in addition  $\phi_0$ is positive, then $\phi$ must be positive as well.